# Is there a way to limit number of packet captures with tcpflow?

Tags: capture, packet, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to limit the number of captured packets, such as

```
tcpdump -c 20
```

but using tcpflow instead. is this possible? console throws a syntax error using -c with tcpflow

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have not used tcpflow myself, but I understand it is more "flow-oriented" than packet-oriented.

From its main page, it seems you cannot limit by number of packets (no option for that), but you **can** limit the number of bytes per flow (`-b`). If you are looking at a limited amount of flows, you may be able to obtain somewhat similar results by manipulating that.